# How did Jesus "hide himself" or "pass through the midst" of mobs intent on killing him?

Tags: john, luke

Early in the Gospel of Luke we read:

> **Luke 4:28-30**: "[The] people in the synagogue were filled with rage... and they got up and drove Him out of the city, and led Him to the brow of the hill on which their city had been built, in order to throw Him down the cliff. *But passing through their midst, He went His way*" (emphasis added).

Similarly, a bit later in John:

> **John 8:59**: "Therefore they picked up stones to throw at Him, but *Jesus hid Himself* and went out of the temple." (emphasis added).

How does anyone merely "hide themselves" or "pass through the midst" of crowds viciously intent on killing them? Surely this means that Christ possessed some prerogative of invisibility, but there seem to be instances in which He could not perform such miracles (cf. Mk. 6:5, 7:24, etc.).

Answer (score 2):

We are not told explicitly how this was done but there are precedents:

- Luke 24:16 - the two men on the road to Emmaus were kept from recognizing Him

The incidents in Luke 4:28-30 and John 8:59 were probably similar.  In both of these Jesus' time had not yet come (John 7:6, 8, 2:4, etc) and thus, Jesus was kept from harm.

However, at the correct time, Jesus declared that His "time had now come" to be sacrificed for sin, John 16:21, 32.

John Wesley made a similar remark when asked if he was afraid of some who were intent on killing him.  He replied, "Until my work on earth is done, I am immortal ..."

Answer (score 0):

Remember that Jesus didn't look like he does in the movies.
He didn't have blue eyes, pale white skin, long straight nose, and flowing blonde hair.
He didn't wear pristine beautiful clothing.
He looked and dressed just like an ordinary person for that time and place.

There were no *Entertainment Tonight* videos, or even *People* magazine photos, so most people wouldn't know it was Jesus if they met him face to face.

The only people that would recognize him were those at the front of the mob.
But once he had passed by those few, or hidden himself until they had moved away, he could walk around just like he was one of the crowd.

Comment: +1 I don't know how good your answer is but it made me smiled :)

Answer (score 0):

You are ignoring the fact that they were not actually committed to kill him. The context show the mob was being violent and dangerous, they wanted to kill him. It wasn't safe for him to stay among them any longer. It must be assumed they were only threatening him, and being aggressive, that he could easily slip away from them. Not every time a mob wants to kill someone succeeds (they were only threatening). He could sneak away, because it was possible. Some versions use a better English word instead of "passing" in [Luke 4:30](https://www.biblegateway.com/verse/en/luke%204:30)

> NTE: But he slipped through the middle of them and went away.
> CEV: But Jesus slipped through the crowd and got away.

> [John 10:39](https://www.biblegateway.com/verse/en/John%2010:39) `NHEB`  Now they sought again to seize him, and he went out of their hand.
> `GNT` Once more they tried to seize Jesus, but he slipped out of their hands.